# Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure, that I'm calling from a c# code using a transaction.
When I run the code in C# (its a console app), instead of getting the result from catch block I'm getting an exception thrown saying:

> Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The
>   transaction is rolled back.

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace app1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string res = "";
            string resDesc = "";

            res = WriteToDB(1,out resDesc);

            Console.WriteLine(res);
            Console.WriteLine(resDesc);


            Console.Read();
        }

        public static string WriteToDB(int val, out string resultDesc)
        {
            resultDesc = "";
            string result = "";
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlAppConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("transcation1");
                try
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = transaction.Connection;
                        cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                        cmd.CommandText = "usp_Test_Proc";
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@check", val);
                        SqlParameter res = cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
                        res.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        SqlParameter resDesc = cmd.Parameters.Add("@resultDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
                        resDesc.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        result = res.Value.ToString().Trim();
                        resultDesc = resDesc.Value.ToString();
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = "Exception";
                    resultDesc = ex.Message;
                    transaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Test_Proc] (
                                            @check        int, 
                                            @result           INT output, 
                                            @resultDesc       VARCHAR(100) 
output) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      SET nocount ON; 
      SET xact_abort ON;             

      IF @check != 0 
        BEGIN 
            BEGIN try              
                SET @result = 0; 
                SET @resultDesc = 'aa'; 
                --RAISERROR('Error from raiserror',1,1)
                THROW 99001, 'Error from throw', 1;
            END try
            BEGIN catch 
                SET @result = 1; 
                SET @resultDesc = concat('catch block',ERROR_MESSAGE()); 
            END catch; 
        END 
        ELSE
        BEGIN
                SET @result = 0; 
                SET @resultDesc = 'done'; 
                end
  END; 

GO
```

When the stored procedure throws an error, instead of going in to the catch block I'm getting an exception back saying "Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back."

But if I run the stored procedure in SSMS it works as expected:
[image]

Why is the result different when I'm calling it from C# code?

Comment: i dont have a transcation inside my stored procedure... do i?... does it have that by default?  My plan was to call the stored procedure inside a loop.. and if all of the succeeds commit the transcation from .NET code otherwise be able to roll back...

Comment: @WilliamXifaras so i should get the result from the catch block when executing the .net code right?

Comment: Check out the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 section Uncommittable Transactions and XACT_STATE

Comment: @WilliamXifaras so the transaction is uncommitable even though I'm handling the error in my code? doesn't that defeat the purpose of error handling... ?

Comment: looks like if i remove SET xact_abort ON;  from the stored procedure then, XACT_STATE() returns 1 and its committable.

Comment: In the `CATCH` block (of the stored procedure) add `IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK`

Comment: Also worth reading: http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html

Comment: @RazvanSocol btw when I add `IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK` in the catch block, i get another error saying: `Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0`

Comment: Why do you need the TRY CATCH in the stored procedure? Your C# already wraps the stored procedure call in a try catch.

Comment: @psj01: I now see that you are also starting a transaction from the client side, but I would recommend against that. Instead, only begin the transaction inside the stored procedure. However, in the `Catch` block in the client you should also have an `IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK` (needed if the stored procedure times out and never reaches the catch block).

Comment: @RazvanSocol the reason I have a transaction on the client side is because I wanted to call this stored procedure inside of a loop and insert some records and if any of them fail, I wanted to roll it back.

Comment: @RazvanSocol also out of curiosity.. .how do i `IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK` in the C# code inside the catch block?

Comment: To execute T-SQL code from C#, you can use another `SqlCommand`, specifying `CommandType.Text`.

Comment: You can call the existing stored procedure from a new one, where you open the transaction and do the loop. To pass multiple rows to that procedure, you can use table-valued parameters, see http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html#ADONET

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have the 'set xact_abort on'.. As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) xact_abort is used to
*Specifies whether SQL Server automatically rolls back the current transaction when a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error.*

Also you need to set the 'state' value to -1 in the [throw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) so that the transaction becomes uncomitable.

Comment: My store procedure doesn't raise or throw any error and I still get the `Uncommittable transaction is detected at the end of the batch. The transaction is rolled back.` It works fine under SSMS